# Django Autocomplete Light - FK Field Results not Forwarding

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm following along in the [DAL documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form) to add a filtered field to my form, but the forwarding isn't working to connect one field to the other:

**Forms.py**

```
class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    commodity = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Commodity.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='commodity-autocomplete'),
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ["variety"]
        widgets = {
            'variety': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='variety-autocomplete', forward=['commodity'],   
        }
```

**Views.py**

```
class VarietyAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Variety.objects.all()

        commodity = self.forwarded.get('commodity', None)
        print("Commodity:" + str(commodity))
        if commodity:
            qs = qs.filter(commodity=commodity)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

I'd like my Variety choices to be filtered by their foreign key relationship to Commodity objects. Both autocomplete fields are working on their own just fine, but the choice from the `commodity` field is not being forwarded to the `VarietyAutocompleteView` (my print command prints `Commodity:None`). Is this perhaps because I am passing a foreign key object? Or have I set this up incorrectly somehow?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem.. How did you finally solve this?

Comment: I switched from DAL over to bootstrap-combobox. I will post my resulting code in an answer.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks a lot!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add for anyone else like me who is thinking "yeah, but I still really don't want to change" - that in practice the line:

```
 'variety': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='variety-autocomplete', forward=['commodity'])
```

Really did not work for me either, but changing it to something like:

```
 'variety': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='variety-autocomplete', forward=('commodity', ))
```

Did work.  Notice that it's a tuple so you need to have a "," there to make it work, as it's supposed to be an iterable value.

I didn't dig much further into why an array is part of the docs and yet doesn't work, but that was the critical change that make my variant work.

Also - I was using a formset (so there were prefixes) and that proved to not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had to scrap DAL and move to [Bootstrap Combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox). It turned out to be really easy to implement, provided you are using the Bootstrap libraries.

This is how it is set up:

Add class `combobox` to the select widget:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from Business.models import Company, Branch
from .models import Variety

class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    variety = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Variety.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'combobox'}),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = [
            "invoice", "contract_date", ...
        ]
```

Then, insert the simplest javascript snip ever:

**inventory_report.html**

```
....

<td style="padding-bottom: 10px">
    <div>Supplier:</div>
    <div>{{ view.purchase_form.supplier }}</div>
</td>

....
{% block scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-combobox.js' %}"></script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Set Text Autofields on New Contract
           $('.combobox').combobox();

        });

    </script>
    {{ view.purchase_form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

That's all there is to it.